Angular Ag-Grid Display Pagination Panel After Certain Limit
I'm using ag-grid to construct the grid config and displaying the grid as per config.
Now, the grid has pagination but its on (displaying pagination panel) since pagination: true property is configured.
Is it possible to display pagination panel once maximum number of rows overflows.
So for example I add some mock property "limit":10 - pagination panel shouldn't be visible till 10 so if 11 row is added add the pagination panel .
I checked ag-grid documentation, didn't find anything, Is this possible to achieve?

Can you plase share ag-grid-angular code?

You have to make pagination value dynamic based on your records.
HTMl file
<ag-grid-angular
    [pagination]="pagination"
    [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
    [paginationPageSizeSelector]="paginationPageSizeSelector"
    [rowData]="rowData"
</ag-grid-angular>

ts file
pagination: boolean = false;

You have to check numbers of records, and based on that you can set your limit to display pagination.
if (this.rowData?.length > 10){
    this.pagination = true
}else{
    this.pagination = false
}


We need to add pagination property in grid options pagination: this.pagination. Later on when the data arrives and when we evaluate and make it boolean as true/false. Its not reevaluating grid options. Hence, pagination remains hidden

@Urvashi when you change the pagination boolean, all you need to do is change the array reference this.gridOptions = [...this.gridOptions] this will trigger the refresh I think! hope it helps! whatever property  is binded to the html using [gridOptions], that property we need to change the reference!

@Naren didn't work, system freezed

Please share some code of table and how you implement it.
